# Target specific UILabel in specific UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building an application in which I click a Start Button and it runs an NSTimer in a label in the selected cell. I'm using one prototype cell and in it I have two labels: the Name and the Time. These labels both have their own tags: 1010 and 1020, respectively. At runtime, there are 10 generated cells. NSArrays are populating the data. Basically, what I'm looking for is to start a timer in the selected cell. I can't seem to do this without having the timer run in every cell. In my project, I am only using one (1) prototype cell with one (1) identifier.

In summary, the problem I keep getting is that the timer goes in every cell. I'm trying to figure out how to target a specific cell. I have stored the cell number. What can I do with that?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and if you would like me to provide more information to help you answer the question, I'd be more than happy to do so!

```
int cellNumber;
BOOL isCurrentlyRunning = NO;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
//Table Data Code
self.peopleArray = @[@"Person 1", @"Person 2", @"Person 3", @"Person 4", @"Person 5", @"Person 6", @"Person 7", @"Person 8", @"Person 9", @"Person 10"];
self.TimeArray = @[@"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.peopleArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleIdentifier"];

    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1010];
    UILabel *lblTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1020];

    NSString *Name, *Time;

    Name = [self.roundOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    lblTime.text = [self formattedTime:self.currentTimeInSeconds];
    lblName.text = Name;

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [_myTimer invalidate];
    self.currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
    cellNumber = [indexPath row];
}

- (int)timeToStop{
    int retVal = 0;
    switch (cellNumber) {
        case 0:
            retVal = 100;
        break;
        default:
            retVal = 200;
        break;
    }
    return retVal;
}
- (NSTimer *)createTimer {
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(timerTicked:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
}
- (NSString *)formattedTime:(int)totalSeconds
{

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
}
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer *)timer {

    _currentTimeInSeconds++;
    if (self.currentTimeInSeconds == [self timeToStop]){
        [_myTimer invalidate];
    }
    self.lblTimer.text = [self formattedTime:_currentTimeInSeconds];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)startCountDown:(id)sender {

    if (!_currentTimeInSeconds) {
        _currentTimeInSeconds = 0 ;
    }
    if (!_myTimer) {
        _myTimer = [self createTimer];
    }
    isCurrentlyRunning = YES;
}
- (IBAction)stopCountDown:(id)sender {

    if(isCurrentlyRunning == YES){
         [_myTimer invalidate];
        isCurrentlyRunning = NO;
    }else{
        if (_myTimer) {
        [_myTimer invalidate];  
    }
        _currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
        self.lblTimer.text = [self formattedTime:_currentTimeInSeconds];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your didSelect method, reload the table view at the end to put the timer in the row that is selected

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

[_myTimer invalidate];
self.currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
cellNumber = [indexPath row];
[tblView reloadData] //replace tblView with the name of your tableView, if you don't have an outlet for it then you can create one by control-dragging it to the VC

}
```

and then

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleIdentifier"];

UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1010];
UILabel *lblTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1020];

NSString *Name, *Time;

Name = [self.roundOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row == cellNumber) {
    lblTime.text = [self formattedTime:self.currentTimeInSeconds];
} else {
    lblTime.text = //whatever you want it to say in the rows without the timer
}
lblName.text = Name;

return cell;
}
```

I think that is what you're asking and if so, that should do it.

The reason the timer was displaying in every row was that you set the timer to the lblTime in every cell; it was not limited in any way, so for every indexPath.row it would show the timer

Comment: Thank you! That simple if statement made all the difference! You are very smart! The only thing I changed was that I put the reloadData inside the timerTicked method, because otherwise it wouldn't show up. Thank you so much though!!!

Comment: Hey @Lucas ! Just noticed something! Could we also retain the data that we put in the cell when we move from cell to cell?

Comment: @Ares What do you mean? Retain the time left on the timer? Retain what cells have been used?

Comment: Actually I was wrong the way I put it earlier...I'm pretty sure I'm having a memory leak error...Whenever I run the timer in a certain cell, the time label goes in another random cell as well! I have no idea what would be causing this...should I post another question?